# Can you switch the order of the determinants when changing variables using the Jacobian?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let say we're changing the variables and we use the Jacobian to do this. Lets say we integrate in respect to $u$ and $v$, does it matter if we set up the integral like $\int\int\,\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$ or $\int\int\,\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}u$ after calculating the Jacobian?

Comment: Yes, it does matter.

Comment: Ok, so based upon the arrangment in which you calculated the Jacobian, you must also arrange the differentials likewise?

Comment: I always see it written using $\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v$ so I should also use this order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think you are asking is (relevant to the question)

> does the Jacobian change if we consider
>   $$
> \newcommand{\pwrt}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
> J = \left|\det \pmatrix{
> \pwrt xu & \pwrt xv\\
> \pwrt yu & \pwrt yv}\right|
> $$
>   as opposed to
>   $$
> \newcommand{\pwrt}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
> J = \left|\det \pmatrix{
> \pwrt xv & \pwrt xu\\
> \pwrt yv & \pwrt yu}\right|
> $$

The answer to this question is no. Switching rows/columns changes the sign but not the magnitude of the determinant of a matrix.

Comment: That's very relevant to what I'm thinking of, so since the Jacobian doesn't change, the order of the differentials you integrate in respect to doesn't matter?

Comment: @ShaneBird Exactly.${}$

Comment: So the Jacobian for the transformation of coordinates is the absolute value of the determinant, is it?

Comment: @zyy that was my understanding at the time, but apparently this definition is not universal. In any case, we integrate using the absolute value of the determinant.